# Product page error when i enabled the development mode in magento 2

Tags: magento2, magento2.4.1

Magento version: 2.4.1

theme: codazon

when Magento is in production mode everything works fine but when I enable development mode, I can't access the product page and I got bellow error:

1 exception(s): Exception #0
(Magento\Framework\Config\Dom\ValidationException): Element 'move',
attribute 'before': [facet 'pattern'] The value '' is not accepted by
the pattern '[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z\d-_.]*|-'. Line: 1766

Element 'move', attribute 'before': '' is not a valid value of the
atomic type 'elementPositionType'. Line: 1766

#1 Magento\Framework\Config\Dom->__construct('createObject('Magento\Framewor...',
array('create('Magento\Framewor...',
array('xml' => '
'/var/www/html/ve...', 'validationState' =>
&Magento\Framework\App\Arguments\ValidationState#000000005269c0cc00000000598efc54#))
called at
[vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/ObjectManager.php:56]
#4 Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\ObjectManager->create('Magento\Framewor...',
array('xml' => '
'/var/www/html/ve...', 'validationState' =>
&Magento\Framework\App\Arguments\ValidationState#000000005269c0cc00000000598efc54#))
called at [vendor/magento/framework/Config/DomFactory.php:43]
#5 Magento\Framework\Config\DomFactory->createDom(array('xml' => ' '/var/www/html/ve...',
'validationState' =>
&Magento\Framework\App\Arguments\ValidationState#000000005269c0cc00000000598efc54#))
called at
[vendor/magento/framework/View/Model/Layout/Update/Validator.php:142]
#6 Magento\Framework\View\Model\Layout\Update\Validator->isValid('

Comment: Please wrap the error using Markdown `code` formatting tool.

Answer (score 0):

Judging by the error, it might be one `<move>` instruction has an error in the syntax, specifically Magento is complaining on the `'before'` attribute. Check all the nodes declared in your layout files, and make sure there is no issue with them. Usually, `'before'` attribute has a dash or another element name as a value, like `before="-"` or `before="element.name"`.

Check more details on DevDocs: https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/frontend-dev-guide/layouts/xml-instructions.html#fedg_layout_xml-instruc_ex_mv

Answer (score 0):

Look like in your `catalog_product_view.xml` you added `before` in `<move>` tag.  which one is not valid as per syntax.

so, find out and remove `before="your_container"`.

and run `php bin/magento cache:clean`.